# Using High Charts with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, charts

I am looking into using High Charts, but I want to populate the data dynamically with PHP and MySQL. 
Looking for an easy way to get data from the DB into the jQuery functions.
This is how the points are created with jQuery (sorry for the big chunk of code).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Tokyo',
                        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                    }, {
                        name: 'New York',
                        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Berlin',
                        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                    }, {
                        name: 'London',
                        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                    }]
                });


            });

        </script>
```

Comment: You're not saying what your database structure looks like, but `json_encode()` is definitely worth a look: http://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: The db structure is sort of irrelevant. I'm more so looking for insight on how to call the php functions and populate the arrays of points. Should an ajax call be made to retrieve the data?

Comment: as said, `json_encode()` will help you turn your database data into Javascript parseable data. You won't need much more. I don't know how Highcharts works, but if you set it up like you show above, it should be sufficient to use PHP to insert the data into the body. If you need to fetch data dynamically after the page has loaded, you'll indeed need Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Highcharts documentation is excellent, I would start there. This is likely the type of graph you want:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

And you want to mess with the Point object:

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#point-object

You are going to want to add the data using jQuery .post or .get commands to get the data from the server.

Comment: Wanted to avoid digging around in their documentation, lol, but it is the right place to start